# how to get an int out of array of 4 chars? I don't understand an answer that was given to me

Tags: c, bit-shift

I have:

```
char a[4];
a[0] = 0x76;
a[1] = 0x58;
a[2] = 0x02;
a[3] = 0x00;
```

and I want to make it an *int*. I got answer like:

```
int32_t i =        0 | 
    a[0] << ( 3 * 8) | 
    a[1] << ( 2 * 8) |
    a[2] << ( 1 * 8) |
    a[3] << ( 0 * 8);
```

But I don't understand, shifting `a[0]` which is a char more than 8 time will give 0, won't it?

Comment: Bit shifting an int 32 times on a 32-bit word will give you a 0. Bit shifting an int 64 times on a 64-bit word will give you a 0. Bit shifting 24, 16, 8, and 0 times (respectively) in this example will not cause you to receive a zero. This is just a different way of applying a 32-bit mask to a 32-bit integer.

Comment: Be aware that `char` is signed on certain platforms.

Answer (score 1):

> shifting a[0] which is a char more than 8 time will give 0, won't it ?

No, the operands of `<<` will be promoted to `int`, if we look at the C99 draft standard section `6.5.7` *Bitwise shift operators* paragraph *3* says:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is
>   that of the promoted left operand. [...]

The *integer promotions* are covered in section `6.3.1.1` *Boolean, characters, and integers* says (*emphasis mine*):

> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. **These are called the integer
>   promotions**.<sup>48)</sup> All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

In this case *int* can represent all the values of *char*.

This assumes *char* is *unsigned* or the values contained in `a` are not negative, otherwise if we are left shifting negative values we are invoking *undefined behavior*, section `6.5.7` paragraph *4* says:

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; [...] If E1 has a signed
>   type and nonnegative value, and E1 x 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Using *unsigned char* will prevent that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature in the language called "integer promotion". Basically it widens the operands to an `int` (if they happen to be of a smaller type) and then applies the designated operation. Only if the result is then saved in a smaller variable, it will be truncated and data will be lost.

Even though such a feature might seem odd, it often makes sense from the hardware perspective. Registers of different widths often overlap with each other (in the case of x86, take `al`, `ax`, `eax` and `rax`), so widening an operand wouldn't incur a high cost. On the other hand, being able to do arithmetic with smaller types while saving the result in a larger type is the main motivator:

```
unsigned char a = 130;
unsigned char b = 140;
int result = a + b; // no overflow
```

Comment: Specifically a 32-bit word size int, in this case.